# Hibernate invents a field on createQuery

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm using hibernate to get data from the database. I have a weird issue.

My entity mapped from the database doesn't have field named "Id" and the table neither.

But when I execute this query :

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select d from MYTABLE d WHERE d.programId = :programID");
query.setParameter("programID", programID);
query.getResultList()
```

I have an exception which is :

```
"T0"."ID" : identificateur non valide
SELECT t0.id, t0.ACHIEVED_BY, etc ...
```

The others fields are in the table and the entity classe but the field ID has been invented.

Do you have any ideas about that ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't paste all the query and entites because the data are private.

Comment: Then you're not providing enough information for us to be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Do Hibernate needs an id for a select ?

Comment: JPA and Hibernate do need *some* ID for all managed entities. There are a number of ways that Hibernate can determine what field or fields are the ID, and we'd have to see your class definition and table schema for that.